# Check if an array contains an element returns an array only with searched element in doctrine query builder

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine

I'm dealing with the following situation:

I have the class ChatRoom with contains an array of users:

```
    #[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: User::class)]
    #[Groups([ChatRoom::GROUP_GET])]
    private iterable $users;
```

I added an extension that is supposed to add to collection operations querys the following:

```
$queryBuilder
     ->leftJoin("$rootAlias.users", 'us')
     ->andWhere('us IN (:current_user)')
     ->setParameter('current_user', array($user->getId()));
```

This will return the right ChatRooms but in the Users array I will only get the one that I'm searching for, not all that are stored in the database.

Any ideea how to solve this..?

Comment: run `echo $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getSQL();` and check if it is generating expected SQL query. Also, you may try `$queryBuilder->setParameter('current_user', [$user]);` but I am not sure.

Comment: It's not generating the expected SQL query.. The join and where clause look like this: LEFT JOIN chat_room_user c3_ ON c0_.id = c3_.chat_room_id 
LEFT JOIN "user" u2_ ON u2_.id = c3_.user_id AND (u2_.deleted_at IS NULL) 
WHERE (u2_.id IN (?)) (where c0_ is my chat_room table). The where id clause should have been on the many to many relationship table. Any ideea how to tell doctrine to do that..?

Answer (score 0):

I did not clearly understand what you are trying to do.

If you need to get all users of current chat room, then no extensions are needed if you have many-to-many chatRoom-user relation. You already have it.

If you need to get all chat rooms of user, you need user-chatRoom relation (via same chat_rooms_users table).

Having these relations you can call getChatRooms() & getUsers() methods. All these features are available via standard Doctrine relations.

Comment: With this extension I'm trying to get all chatrooms where the logged user is in the chatRoom->getUsers() array. It is doing so, but in the getUsers() array it will only return the logged user, the other won't because of how doctrine generates the query. You can see it in my comment from the post above.

Comment: Doctrine will hydrate objects from data received in the query. So if you join only 1 user, only 1 user will be available in the resulted object collection. 

To do what you need, you need to declare many-to-many relation on users to chat rooms. Smth like this:

`class User {
  #[ManyToMany(targetEntity="ChatRoom", inversedBy="users")]
  #[JoinTable(name="chat_rooms_users")]
  private iterable $chatRooms;
}`

Maybe, add with some JoinColumn settings to specify correct table columns.

Comment: I don't understand how this would help me with returning only chatrooms where logged user is a participant... So I have to give up on my doctrine extension?

Comment: You can keep track of chat rooms where user logged in by relation. With properly defined relation if you access $this->chatRooms inside User object Doctrine will load all associated chat rooms. After calling ChatRooms's getUsers() method Doctrine will load all users from this ChatRoom. So there is no need in extra extensions. Everything comes out-of-the-box with Doctrines relations :)